# common POM based plugins across multiple microservice projects

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, microservices

I am trying to figure out a way to import a set of common Maven plugins, across multiple microservice projects?

Idea is to maintain a single place to manage all the common plugins - like jacoco, javadocs etc.

We totally want to avoid the parent POM way of handling it.

Comment: Make a parent project and define them their and use the parent in your other projects..?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking for solution other than the parent POM way.

Comment: Why do you need different than the parent POM way?

Answer (score 1):

The Maven way to do this is to have a parent POM. You can either construct a multi-module project or have an external parent POM.

Maven has no way of "importing xml" into a given POM, except for the `<scope>import</scope>` for dependencyManagement. So you cannot define a set of plugins, properties etc. and just import them.